# Add two list together where the start of each list will be added to the other

Tags: python

I feel like this concept is pretty easy but I'm just having a hard time grasping what to do.

Example:

```
list1: [super, cool, huge]
list2: [dog, cat, mouse]
```

What I'm trying to get is a single list being: `[superdog, coolcat, hugemouse]`

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this would be using list comprehension as posted by user [d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7128934/d-b)

```
[x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

I guessing by the question that you are new to python and computer science in general (apologies if you are not and this offends you) so here is a bit of detail on how this works.

List comprehension is used for making lists (obviously). The syntax is:

[ *expression* for *item* in *iterable* if *condition* == True ]

`zip()` is a built-in function which combines two lists

```
zip(list1, list2)
# Returns <zip at 0x18db1d949c0>
list(zip(list1, list2))
# Returns [('super', 'dog'), ('cool', 'cat'), ('huge', 'mouse')]
```

You need to use `zip(list1, list2)` as you cannot put in two iterables into list comprension. However, using zip you input a single iterable containing the combination of both lists.

The item used `x` and `y` refer to the first and second value in each of the tuples in the list. Which means the the expression would be `x + y` which is `super + dog` which is `superdog`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop

```
i = 0
ans = [0,0,0] # Assigning randomly 0 to all indices
while i<3:
    ans[i] = list1[i]+list2[i]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem. The list comprehension from @d.b and @stuupid is a compact way to do it, but might be a little confusing if you're just getting started in Python.

All of the techniques boil down to somehow iterating through a list. Let's start with your lists. I changed all of the items inside your lists to strings, since that's what I think you really wanted

```
list1 = ['super', 'cool', 'huge']
list2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
```

The most common way to iterate through a list might be with a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). You can do

```
for item in list1:
    print(item)
```

which gives

```
super
cool
huge
```

using the [range function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is a very common construct for a for loop:

```
for i in range(3):
    print(i)
```

which gives

```
0
1
2
```

You can combine range() with [len()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to get the *indexes* of a list:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    print(i)
```

gives

```
0
1
2
```

Getting back to your problem. We can use the range(len()) trick to step through the indices of list1 and fill in a new list on the fly:

```
list1 = ['super', 'cool', 'huge']
list2 = ['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
list3 = []    # new empty list

for i in range(len(list1)):
    list3.append(list1[i] + list2[i])

print(list3)
```

which gives

```
['superdog', 'coolcat', 'hugemouse']
```

This is a very basic way to approach this problem and it takes advantage of the fact that `list1` and `list2` have the same number of items. A safer way to solve the problem would be to do some len() comparisons between the lists to make sure they are the same length.